# Live ticker Research - with Ajax and PHP or Socket.io and Node.js or maybe Flash or Ruby on Rails

Tags: ajax, node.js, socket.io, ticker, news-ticker

I am working on a Project where I will try to compare different ways of creating a live ticker (news-ticker or sport-ticker whatever). I would also like to make benchmark tests, like how many connected users or how fast the data will come.

I have googled and found that usually tickers are build in PHP as the server and the client has an ajax call for every 30 seconds which will return the new Data.
Another way of doing this is with websockets (socket.io) and node.js!
With those two, I have worked and experimentet!

But are the other ways of building tickers?

Obviously you may replace any server-side language with php but are the other ways that the server sends data to the client?

Maybe with Flash ? or Ruby on Rails?

It would help if somebody could point out common ways of tickers and also modern ways or fast ways. I will then choose two of them and compare them!

I would really appreciate if someone knows good articles or links about this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on your requirements (update rate, etc.). I means if you update the news only a couple times a day, you will have some overhead if you maintain a Websocket open for nothing. All server technologies will do the same thing if you are requesting the data every 30 seconde or something like that, it is a typical ajax call. Did you considered using something that is already build like [Jquery News Ticket](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/)

Comment: I want smthg like a sport ticker, which means data will come from the server at latest every 30 seconds! Which means a websocket connection is no overhead I think!..But thats what I want to figure out ;)...Yes I have seen the jQuery News Ticket ...it might be one way the other probably websocket...and I guess I will compare those two!